# Doctrine where not

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-1.2

I have a table in DB like that

i want to select all except the record contain (x=1, y=1) i mean the id=8

```
id  |  x  |  y
---------------
1   |  2  |  1
2   |  0  |  1
3   |  5  |  6
4   |  6  |  4
5   |  7  |  4
6   |  7  |  4
7   |  5  |  7
8   |  1  |  1
```

Comment: do want `x!=y` or just `x!=1` and `y!=1`? if `x!=1` and `y!=1` there is multiple `y=1`

Comment: id 1,2 will be affected if you want `y!=1`

Comment: yeah, i want if y=1 and x = anything it's ok .... the only case i want to eliminate whe x=1 and y=1

Comment: just add "where x!=1 and y!=1" it will do

Comment: something like x=2 and y=1 ... it will not selected...right?

Comment: @user1272589 try my answer, I have provided the demo also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: see the [**DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dd008/2/0)

```
select * from TableName where 1 NOT IN(x,y)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
SELECT * FROM TableName where x!=1 OR y!=1
```

Comment: something like x=2 and y=1 ... it will not selected

Comment: ok now check my updated query, it will work... you can now get all the records where y=1 and x=anything

Comment: i want to select all record except the record contain (x=1, y=1)

Answer (score 1):

Following doctrine should work for you.

> Doctrine_Query::Create()
>   ->from("tablename")
>   ->where("x != 1 AND Y != 1")
>   ->fetchArray();

Answer (score 0):

you can try this-

```
select * from TableName where x!=1 and y!=1
```

Comment: something like x=2 and y=1 ... it will not selected

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 SELECT * FROM test where 1 NOT IN(x) OR 1 NOT IN (y)
```

see demo... http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dd008/12